# How sample mean and standard deviation (error) change if sample size is significant compared to population size (n>>0.05*N)?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, sample-size

> How do sample mean and standard deviation (error) change if sample size is significant compared to population size?

Things I Know So Far:
If a population has a mean of $X$ and a standard deviation of $SD$, then a sample with $n$ size will have a mean of $x$ and a standard deviation of $\frac{SD}{\sqrt n}$ as long as $n$ is too small compared to the population size.

So my question is how the sample mean and sample standard deviation change if $n$ is not so small. **And more importantly, why?**

Comment: Can you define *significant to population size*? Also, consider using simulations to see how things behave in practice. E.g. generate a population of size $N$ from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution. Sample $n$ elements from it and obtain the sample mean and sample variance. Repeat $m$ times and plot your estimates. Change $N,n,\mu$ and/or $\sigma$ and try again. You may discover that part of what you write here is incorrect.

Comment: I think you main question has to do with sampling with or without replacement. If the sample size is more than about 10% of population size, in sampling without replacement you need to use a finite population correction for the standard error. If sampling is with replacement and population $\sigma$ is known (not estimated by $S),$ then a 95% z confidence interval for population mean $\mu$ is $\bar X\pm 1.96\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ Look carefully at formulas for CIs in your text..//Strictly speaking "significant to sample size" does not make sense.